# How to seed data only once before running all tests using MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mstest

I have bunch of tests class such as `CustomerTest`, `ProductTest`, `VendorTest` and so on. I'm using in-memory Database and I would like to seed all data that I need to ONLY ONCE before running all these Tests above but have no idea how to do it.

I have `CustomWebApplicationFactory` class

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    public ApplicationContext context { get; set; }
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext>));
            if (descriptor != null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options
                .UseInMemoryDatabase("testDB")
            );

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationContext>();
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                SeedData(db); //seeding all data to all table
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My Tests class

```
[TestClass]
public class VendorTest : BaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AddVendor()
    {
        var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            new
            {
                name = "VENDORTEST"
            }
        );

        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(
            "vendors",
            new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        );

        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetVendor()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("vendors");
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

Base Test

```
public class BaseTest
{
    protected static CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _webAppFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    protected static HttpClient _httpClient = _webAppFactory.CreateDefaultClient();

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        //not sure if BaseClass is the way to do it
        //_httpClient = _webAppFactory.CreateDefaultClient();
    }
}
```

Everytime a `TestMethod` is running, it will reseed all of the data due to `CustomWebApplicationFactory`. Any idea how to do it only once?

Comment: Add Vendor is writing to the database.  So you only need to add the vendor once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I dislike your idea so much, that I hesitated to show you a possible approach. I'll explain that after the code.

If you need something, that runs only once, `static` things come to mind. So, you could use a static/singleton factory to create your in-memory database like this:

```cs
public class TestDbFactory
{
   private static TestDbFactory instance;

   private readonly ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   private TestDbFactory()
   {
      var databaseName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      var inMemoryContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>()
          .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName)
          .Options;

      this.applicationContext = new ApplicationContext(inMemoryContextOptions);
      this.InitDatabase();
   }

   public static TestDbFactory Instance => CreateOrReuseInstance();

   public ApplicationContext ApplicationContext => this.applicationContext;
   
   private static TestDbFactory CreateOrReuseInstance()
   {
      if (instance != null) return instance;
      var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
      instance = instance ?? new TestDbFactory();
      semaphore.Release(1);

      return instance;
   }

   private void InitDatabase()
   {
      // ensure deleted & created & seeded for this.applicationContext
   }
}
```

Now you can either use `TestDbFactory.Instance.ApplicationContext` to pass the database to the systems under test or you can use the factory pattern of the dependency injection setup to provide the context:

```cs
services.AddScoped(_ => TestDbFactory.Instance.ApplicationContext);
```

What I don't like about your idea:

1. Even for a single test you have to seed the whole database.
2. You can't do write test, because then tests don't have a predictable setup (it might be or not, that the db contents have changed before a test runs).
3. To me a test also serves as documentation. This is not possible, if the database content relevant for a specific test can't be determined from the test.
4. Adding new tests and updating the seeding will become a nightmare as you (let alone a whole team) have to verify the new data vs. all existing tests.
5. You won't save much typing as you still have to data for every test.

So, to me a better approach would be to use an in-memory database in every test class (a test class contains all tests for a single method). It would be ok to provide a basic seeding common to all tests in the test class, but specific data setup for a test should go with the test.

I hope that this post helps in one way or the other.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I'm better off with creating and deleting in-memory database for every test class and seeding only necessary data? Yeah now that I think about it, it might be a better idea this way. I was thinking of seeding data at once so that I don't have to keep reseeding same data but it can be done by creating common seed and the 2nd problem is that creating and deleting new in-memory DB takes a while and I have a lot of tests method so I thought I could save time if I only need to do it once.